# What point in time does a manual AWS Aurora snapshot represent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

### Process

1. You click "Take snapshot"
2. You wait some amount of time while the snapshot is being created. During this time, changes continue to be made to the database.
3. The snapshot is completed.

### Question

Does the snapshot exactly represent the database at stage 1 (the exact time you clicked "Take snapshot"), or are any or all changes made to the database during step 2 reflected in the snapshot?

Comment: This probably works same as EBS snapshots, so its point 1 only. Everything after you initiate creation of the snapshot, is not included, even if snapshot takes long time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

### My findings

I want to be wrong, but I tested twice and found that snapshots do reflect changes made between the time you start the snapshot and the time the snapshot is completed (at least when taking a snapshot through the console).

Here's how I tested:

1. Click "Take snapshot"
2. Make a change to the database
3. Wait for the snapshot to finish
4. Restore the snapshot to a new database
5. Connect to the new database and see if the change is present

**The change was present in the new database**

### Alternate approach

The only way I know to truly take a snapshot at a specific point in time (without stopping the db) is to:

1. Wait until the time has passed
2. Use "Restore to point in time" to build a new database from that specific moment
3. Take a snapshot from the new database
4. Delete that new database